# Как стилизовать checkbox без использования дополнительных библиотек

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ребят, подскажите как стилизовать checkbox без использования дополнительных библиотек ? Чтобы сделать чекбокс такой как в макете?

Comment: В каком маркете?

Comment: Дали тестовый макет который нужно сверстать, но я не знаю как поставить чекбокс  который изображен в макете, вопрос заключается в том, как мне это сделать  ?

Comment: В целом можно поступить так: верстаете свой контрол, поверх кнопки кладете label с указанием на нативный контрол чекбокса, делаем его opacity = 0, а размеры подгоняем по элементу нашего нового чекбокса.

Answer (score 3):

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:-1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" />
<label for="box1">checkbox #1</label>
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/kb67J/1/.

Вместо `color` и текста вставьте в `label` картинки фоном.